# Should we bring the apprenticeship back?

Tags: apprenticeship, opinion

I've been reading that experience counts more than formal schooling when it comes to looking for a job. There aren't many schools that teach sound design separately.

I know that some, like the tattoo industry, still use an apprenticeship model - the apprentice pays a fee directly to the master-in-resident in order to receive on-the-job sound design training. In most other industries, the apprentice is the one who gets paid.

It might work. The student gets meaningful experience that is most likely less expensive than an audio recording school, and the master gets paid. Of course, the student will probably still have to clean the toilets and whatnot, just because it has to be done.

Maybe there could be more virtual internships like this one: http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/need-a-mentor

It's just a passing thought, but do you guys think old-school apprenticeships are worth considering?

Answer (score 2):

Love the idea.  Bummer about the laws that make this difficult, however, there's always loopholes.

I often work out of my home studio.  When I work on a stage there isn't really a place for an apprentice.  I would be open to having an "Intern" or "Apprentice" at my studio, but I'm not quite sure how the logistics of that would work.

Has anyone here ever worked with an Apprentice in a home studio environment?

Comment: I'd love to be your apprentice

Comment: Related question: what would you say would be the minimum required knowledge to start an internship/apprenticeship? Maybe credits on some games or films? Working knowledge of protools?

Comment: @Kurt - Would be interesting trying to get that to work from a different continent.

Comment: @Mercy - Depends on the level of the apprenticeship.  In most cases, I wouldn't say any credits would be required.  Very good relationship with the software in use would be good, plus a fairly good understanding of proper workflow, etc...  We have 4 or 5 interns on the stage I work on.  All of them are students, none have any notable related credit.  However, all of them are Pro Tools certified (at the 210 level).  That's always a plus, but not entirely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I know that at least in the U.S., there are labor laws that make this all but impossible. The apprentice type jobs have turned into either paying gigs (which means there are fewer of them), or internships. Internships are great if you can find them, but because of those laws, and the liabilities associated with them, most places require that you be receiving academic credit for those internships.

Tim is a saint for running that little program of his. It would be wonderful if more apprenticeships were available, I know I would have appreciated it when I was getting started.

I think if we can expand the online community and its resources, kind of like what Andrew has done in creating this website, there can be something that might come close to replacing the "old" apprenticeship model. Hopefully in a positive way, because I recognize that change is not ALWAYS good.

Comment: I know that GANG is trying to set up some sort of mentorship program thing, but I haven't heard much about it. Maybe I should get a membership . . . 